# Java - Convert Filepath to image

Tags: java, string, image

Is there any way I can convert this string:

```
D:\Projects\Epic MC mod\fabric-example-mod\run\.\screenshots\2021-06-13_20.24.30.png
```

To the image, 2021-06-13_20.24.30.png?
As in being able to run

```
Image image = D:\Projects\Epic MC mod\fabric-example-mod\run\.\screenshots\2021-06-13_20.24.30.png
```

And getting that image as a result?

Answer (score 1):

You could use "javax.imageio.ImageIO":

```
try {
       Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: That won’t compile, due to invalid string escapes.

Comment: I meant the file path in general, will adjust that accordingly